# Can I temporarily keep my Windows partition to recover data?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I want to install Ubuntu onto a machine with windows but the amount of backup data is too large for me to transfer without bringing in another computer.

Can I install Ubuntu as a dual-boot with a resizable partition, transfer my data to the Ubuntu partition, and then remove the Windows partition sizing the Ubuntu partition over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to do that you will use the GParted app, hope it solved your doubt :)

Comment: That it did, let the install commence! Thx

Comment: You should also say *how* to accomplish his goal.