# Help required in migrating to ubuntu completely

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I have Windows 10 on my HP Elitebook dual-booted with Ubuntu 22.04. The primary partition ofc has windows in it. I have decided to ditch Windows entirely and go with Ubuntu. I would like to know how it can be done without any data loss. Also, while doing this do I need a USB of higher storage? The Windows partition occupies around 222GB of the hard disk

Comment: This question might be too broad, as there are multiple ways to do this. I would backup my Windows data, reformat the Windows partition as a Unix partition, and add that partition to my Ubuntu system. Then I would restore the backed up Windows data to the Ubuntu system. What that means for your USB storage is impossible to say. Not all of the 222GB will be user data, but probably the largest part.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You do not write how experienced you are doing disk partitioning etc. So assuming you are not - I suggest you buy an external USB stick and copy your windows data onto this and then subsequently format the entire disk from the ubuntu installer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Since you have a dual boot already, I guess you are familiar with Ubuntu and partitioning. Please open a terminal and type `df -h` and edit the result into your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I temporarily keep my Windows partition to recover data?](https://askubuntu.com/q/405539/) or simply use an external storage disk that has a bit more storage capacity than the total size of all of the files from Windows that you want to back up.

Answer (score 0):

The only way not to have data loss is to have a few good and current backups of your own personal data (Documents, Pictures, ...). If you have this, you are fully covered, and nothing can go wrong whatsoever. Operating systems do not need backup. They can be downloaded all over the place. Your data, however, once lost, is lost forever.

The easiest way for you to proceed (which I do all the time) is to install Ubuntu, having it use the entire disk. Then place your data back and do some configuration. In less than two hours, you will be up and running.